# How to generate a record type Id?

Tags: apex, record-type, id

Using the `IDGenerator` class, [used on FFLib](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/blob/master/force-app/libs/fflib-apexmocks/classes/fflib_IDGenerator.cls), how can I generate a RecordType object Id?

It is impossible to use `IDGenerator.generate(RecordType.SobjectType)`.

If not possible to get the sObjectType, is there a way to get just the prefix of a record type object?

Comment: The RecordType prefix is '012'.

Comment: @cropredy pointed out that it's because `RecordType.SObjectType` is actually a `SObjectField` instead of an `SObjectType`. You can reference it by other means, such as `sObjectType.RecordType.sObjectType` or `RecordType.Id.getSobjectType()`, etc. It's rather unfortunate that this one object is broken relative to everything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the key prefix with getKeyPrefix:

```
String keyPrefix = SObjectType.RecordType.getKeyPrefix();
```

IDGenerator should also work in this case, as it's basically doing the same thing you would be doing.

Comment: see my answer how you have to tweak the arg to fflib_IdGenerator for `RecordType`

Answer (score 4):

The reason why `IDGenerator.generate(RecordType.SobjectType)` doesn't work is that SobjectType is a field name on SObject RecordType and you can't compile the expression

This works though:

```
fflib_IdGenerator.generate(new RecordType().getSobjectType())
```

Comment: Ah, yes. That explains a lot. Your method isn't necessary, though, you can also write the rather obtuse: `sObjectType.RecordType.sObjectType` as well.

Comment: @sfdcfox ah good point.  I never used that construction before

Answer (score 2):

Worth noting fflib Id generator fails after 1000 Id's. I've ported it into something simpler:

```
static Id getId(String keyPrefix, Decimal n){
    String fakeIdPrefix = '000000000000'.substring(0, 12 - n.precision());
    return Id.valueOf(keyPrefix + fakeIdPrefix + n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile they enabled a one-liner:

```
return type.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + (fakeIdCount+++'').leftPad(15, '0')
```